# How do I use Firebase Parameterized configuration with Typescript when setting region() on a Firebase Function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

As per [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#params) I am trying to use a Firebase Parameterized configuration directly inside the `region()` config for a function.

I have a `.env` file like so:

```dotenv
LOCATION = 'australia-southeast1';
```

And a `config` file like so:

```TypeScirpt
import { defineString } from 'firebase-functions/params';
export const LOCATION = defineString('LOCATION');
```

And now I want to use that Parameterized configuration inside the `region()` config for my function.

**Attempt 1:**
I tried to provide the param directly [as the docs suggest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#params):

```TypeScript
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { LOCATION } from './config';
const sydneyFunctions = functions.region(LOCATION); // <-- ERROR HERE
```

But TypeScript gives me this error:

> Argument of type 'StringParam' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

**Attempt 2:**
I tried using `LOCATION as unknown as string` to cast it to a string and thus avoid the TypeScript error:

```TypeScript
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { LOCATION } from './config';
const sydneyFunctions = functions.region(LOCATION as unknown as string);
```

But that produces this error during deployment:

> HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/'australia-southeast1';' (or it may not exist).

**Attempt 3:**
I tried using `LOCATION.value()` like so:

```TypeScript
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { LOCATION } from './config';
const sydneyFunctions = functions.region(LOCATION.value());
```

But the deployment fails with a similar error:

> HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/' (or it may not exist)

Using `LOCATION.toString()` and `LOCATION.value().toString()` also give similar errors.

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had the wrong `.env` format.

It should look like this:

```dotenv
LOCATION="australia-southeast1"
```

And with that correction `LOCATION as unknown as string` worked to cast the `StringParam` to `string` (attempt 1 from my question).

It looks like this:

```TypeScipt
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { LOCATION } from './config';
const sydneyFunctions = functions.region(LOCATION as unknown as string);
```