# Type Mismatch Problems While Setting region Property for Gen 2 Firebase Functions using TypeScript and a Parameterized Variable

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Issue Description:**

I am having trouble setting the `region` property of my Gen 2 Firebase Functions using TypeScript and a parameterized variable due to type mismatch issues. Here's a sample of my `.env` file:

```
LOCATION="australia-southeast1"
```

I have attempted to define the `region` both globally and at the function level.

**1. Defining region globally using `setGlobalOptions`**

I would prefer to define the `region` globally using `setGlobalOptions`.

The global `region` property on `setGlobalOptions` has a type of `GlobalOptions.region?: string | Expression<string> | ResetValue | undefined`. This is slightly different from the function level type `HttpsOptions.region?: string | string[] | Expression<string> | ResetValue | undefined` as the global level only allows for a singular `string` and no `string[]`.

No matter what I do at the global level, it fails. All three of these attempts give a deployment error `Error: Illegal type coercion of param LOCATION to type string[]`:

```TypeScript
setGlobalOptions({
  region: defineString("LOCATION"),
});
```

```TypeScript
setGlobalOptions({
  region: defineString("LOCATION") as unknown as string,
});
```

```TypeScript
setGlobalOptions({
  region: defineList("LOCATION") as unknown as string,
});
```

Therefore, I am unsure how to define `region` on `setGlobalOptions` using a parameterized variable.

**2. Defining region at the function level**

When I tried defining `region` at the function level, the IDE showed `region` as `HttpsOptions.region?: string | string[] | Expression<string> | ResetValue | undefined`.

I thought `defineString()` would work as it returns a `string`. Although there were no errors in the IDE, during deployment I received this error `Error: Illegal type coercion of param LOCATION to type string[]`.

```TypeScript
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { testValidators } from "../../../services/tests";
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params";

export const functionName = onCall(
  {
    region: defineString("LOCATION"),
  },
  (request) => {
    testValidators(request);
  }
);
```

Next, I tried to define the `region` using `defineList()`, but that produced a type error in the IDE:

```TypeScript
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { testValidators } from "../../../services/tests";
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params";

export const functionName = onCall(
  {
    region: defineList("LOCATION"),
  },
  (request) => {
    testValidators(request);
  }
);
```

Here is the IDE error:

```
Type 'ListParam' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | Expression<string> | ResetValue | undefined'.
  Type 'ListParam' is not assignable to type 'Expression<string>'.
    The types returned by 'value()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The following works, but it is confusing because `region` should accept a `string`, so why do I need to use `defineList()` and further assert it with `defineList("LOCATION") as unknown as string[]`?

```TypeScript
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { testValidators } from "../../../services/tests";
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params";

export const functionName = onCall(
  {
    region: defineList("LOCATION") as unknown as string[],
  },
  (request) => {
    testValidators(request);
  }
);
```

Overall there seems to be a lot of problems with the typing for `region` both at the function and global level.

I managed to get the function level working with an assertion, but I would still prefer to use `region` on `setGlobalOptions` with a parameterized variable.

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

**Environment:**

- Node.js: 16.16.0
- firebase-functions: 4.4.1
- firebase-tools: 12.4.4
- firebase-admin: 11.10.1

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer with `setGlobalOptions` working with `defineList`, can you check once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6204) and Google has put out a [fix](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/6205) that will be merged soon.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76569183/20239914) provided by **Jed Choi** you have to set the region using `DefineList` as unknown then use it as `region: <string[]>secret_value,`
Here’s updated code for you :

```js
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { testValidators } from "../../../services/tests";
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params";

// you must specify type as unknown explicitly
const location:unknown = defineList("LOCATION")

export const functionName = onCall(
  {
    region: <string[]>location, // you should cast as sting[]
  },
  (request) => {
    testValidators(request);
  }
);
```

If you choose to use firebase functions gen1 then you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75643113/20239914)

#### Update:

**I have tested** : You can set the region globally with `setGlobalOptions` with the `defineList` but you need to specify it as a string so at runtime you will get delimiter `,` :

```js
import { setGlobalOptions } from "firebase-functions/v2/options";
import { defineList } from "firebase-functions/params";

const region = defineList("REGIONS", {
    default: ["australia-southeast1", "asia-east1"]
});

setGlobalOptions({
  region: region as unknown as string
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not sure what extra information this provides. When setting `region` at the function level this is the same as using `defineList("LOCATION") as unknown as string[]`. And I have already outlined that in the question. Maybe you have some advice for how to use that at the global level with `setGlobalOptions`? Because that would solve the main problem.